# Cursor color in Eclipse 3.5/Zend Studio 7 on Mac OS X

Tags: eclipse, themes, zend-studio

Does any of you have a clue on how to change the cursor color in Zend Studio 7.0 on Mac OS X?

I am asking because I really fancy dark colored themes. After a few hours I managed to port my favorite theme from TextMate.app. However my cursor is still black, which is somehow troublesome.

As you can see here - http://twitpic.com/f7ywc - the cursor becomes pretty invisible, right?

Please help me out here.
Btw - anyone interested in the theme?

All the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I love TextMate and its twilight theme, so this issue is dear to me.  I think Eclipse for Mac just can't set the caret color due to an [SWT bug](http://forums.aptana.com/viewtopic.php?p=9211&sid=7a051ccaf85bf32c95f58c75c292c378#p9211).

In the meantime, you can enable line highlighting to make just the current line have a slightly lighter background.  This worked for me:

1. Open Preferences and go to General -> Editors -> Text Editors
2. Check "Highlight current line"
3. In the scrolling list at the bottom, set "Current line highlight" to a medium-dark gray.

Comment: This one was the closest I ever got to solving my issue. Thanks for the tip, Kevin!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a much better solution for Eclipse 3.5 is to use the Carbon build instead of Cocoa.  Cocoa seems to force a black cursor but I didn't have this problem with Carbon.  To my surprise it's also a *lot* faster to scroll through code in Carbon.