# How do I change text cursor color in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How do I change the text cursor color in the Eclipse IDE for Windows?

I want to change *only* the color of the cursor, but I can`t find an option to do this. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

You can find these settings in:

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> Text Editors: Appearance color options

AND

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance-> Colors and Fonts: in the Basic Folder

Comment: What a name of option that change TEXT CURSOR color ?

Comment: Any ideas why I wouldn't have Preferences under Window?

Comment: Oh, maybe it's because this was 5 years ago

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find one just for the cursor when using Eclipse for PHP, but you might try changing the current line color to be a bit lighter/darker if you are having trouble seeing the cursor (ref: [How to change the color of current line & text selection in eclipse (for Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652528/how-to-change-the-color-of-current-line-text-selection-in-eclipse-for-java),  [Cursor color in Eclipse 3.5/Zend Studio 7 on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328795/cursor-color-in-eclipse-3-5-zend-studio-7-on-mac-os-x).)

Comment: This seems like it would be really obvious, but while playing around with themes I somehow set the current line color to something other than the background color and as a result I couldn't see the blinking cursor anymore. Setting the current line back to black gave me back the look and feel I was missing and I don't know that I would have thought of it but for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you here.
Its not in control of Eclipse, its the mouse's property.
Navigate to Control Panel-> Select "Large Icons" from top right drop down->Mouse->Pointers->Text Select->Browse->Select an appropriate black thick pointer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cursor color is implicitly changed when you set

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> TextEditors **Current Line Highlight**

Until today there is no way to set it independently (Eclipse Neon.1)

If you want a black **background color** like me, set this one with a custom RGB 30, 30, 30, and **Current Line highlight** BLACK (the cursor while turn White)

Answer (score 0):

This is a late reply. I am having the same problem and couldn't find anyway to fix it in eclipse.

Turns out that I can change the text selection icon in the Window setting. Search for Mouse properties and change the text selection to beam_i.cur. It gives me a much better contrast!

FYI, my system is win10.

Answer (score -1):

Duffy356's answer is correct, but incomplete:  the selection background color under the appearance color options appears to be the cursor color from my experience.

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> TextEditors: Change Line number foreground under Appearance color options

Comment: No, **Selection background color** has nothing to do with Cursor color neither **Line Number foreground**.